# Time in Milliseconds Alarm

Tags: android, calendar, timepicker

Okay, So I'm working on having an alarm that gives a notification at, lets say 3:00 PM daily, but I want this to be selectable by the user, between AM/PM, and Hours/Min freely changeable. I will probably use a `TimePicker`, and this is my code I have so far:

```
    public void startAlarm() {


            Intent intent = new Intent(currentDay.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(currentDay.this,0, intent,0);

            long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            firstTime += 15*1000;


            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,firstTime,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);


        }
```

So, I figure I'm going to be using something along the lines of:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
```

and then using

```
cal.getTimeInMillis()
```

But this doesn't work, any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: So, long story short, I know how to get the current time, then add lets say 15 seconds to it, but I want to have a definite time that WORKS for example 5:14 PM, and everything I've tried doesn't work

Comment: when I put `cal.getTimeInMillis()` in where `firstTime` is, lets say that time comes up, nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are getting a Calendar instance with the current date/time and then you are adding 19 hours and 45 minutes to it, NOT setting the time of the Calendar instance explicitly to 19:45. Is that what you are meaning to do? You need to use the Calendar set() method to set an explicit time.

From the API reference for [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

> Calendar's getInstance method returns a calendar whose locale is based on system settings and whose **time fields have been initialized with the current date and time**:
>
> ```
>     Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
> ```

```
public abstract void add (int field, int value)

Since: API Level 1
Adds the specified amount to a Calendar field.
Parameters
    field   the Calendar field to modify.
    value   the amount to add to the field.
    Throws IllegalArgumentException if field is DST_OFFSET or ZONE_OFFSET.
```

**EDIT:** To convert local time to UTC...

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
int offset = cal.getTimeZone().getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());
firstTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() + offset;
```

NOTE: I haven't tried the above and there may be an easier way but it should work. It's hard for me to test stuff like this as my timezone is GMT/UTC.

Comment: Let me try that out, but it looks perfect, when I read through the APIs I misunderstood set() as setting system clock, and if you wouldn't mind voting the original post back up to 0, i think it was dumb to be voted down because it was a valid question.

Comment: @Samuel: Hopefully it will help. As for the down vote, you need to be careful around here about making your question as clear as possible. I'm not sure down votes are always a malicious thing - more an indicator that the Q doesn't explain enough. You can always edit your original Q to add extra information and use the @ syntax in comments to someone you think has down voted you so your response appears in their 'replies'. Anyway, up voted again.

Comment: @Samuel: ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP is a time since last boot. You probably need to look at RTC_WAKEUP which is 'wall clock time in UTC' and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that's so obvious, ill give that a try. Hit me up with an email, id like to be friends, I'm still pretty young and have some dumb questions when I can't figure things out, tthanks I'm in bed now, but ill try that right after school

Comment: @Samuel: Are you adjusting the cal.getTimeInMillis() result to match your timezone? RTC_WAKEUP needs a date/time in UTC (which is the same as GMT). If, for example, your timezone is 5 hours behind GMT, you will need to subtract 5 * 3600 * 1000 milliseconds from cal.GetTimeInMillis().

Comment: How would this be done to match any timezone, for example two people using the same application, in two different time zones?

Comment: @MisterSquonk I've been trying this, but it's also not working, and doesn't `Calendar.getInstance()` get the timezone too? so isn't this repetitive?

Comment: `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(tz);` seemed to work great for me! but otherwise great! thanks for being so patient/helpful!

Comment: OK - I just edited the example to use cal.getTimeZone().getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis()) which should now also work (I tried a test by faking another timezone in cal). Glad you seem to have something working for you and glad to help - I always learn something myself when trying to solve other peoples' problems. :)

Comment: Why calculate the offset here? `Calendar.getTimeInMillis`already gives you the time in milliseconds since UTC 1970.

Comment: @Che Jami: Sorry, I only just spotted your comment/question.`Calendar.getTimeInMillis` returns the 'natural' time, in other words it doesn't take the daylight savings in to account. The offset is used to compensate for that. The code above is used in an app I wrote to display a TV Guide and is in use by various people around the world - I originally thought `Calendar.getTimeInMillis` would compensate for daylight savings automatically until I was contacted by some users who told me the TV Guide times were out by 1 hour after their phones had adjusted to daylight savings time.

Comment: @MisterSquonk Does `Calendar.getTimeInMillis` need to compensate for anything? Ideally, the value is the same across the world at any given time (not timezone biased). Daylight savings translates into a timezone change, such as in the UK we shift from GMT+0 to GMT+1 (BST). Timezones are just a view on this millisecond value.